# different results when converting byte to blob and back again from blob to byte in java

Tags: java

I have a task that converts a fingerprint template into byte array (serialize). then I compared the two byte arrays before converting it into blob and after converting it back from byte arrray to blob. they're giving me different results when i print them.
here's the code

```
`Blob blob = con.createBlob();
blob.setBytes(1, enroller.getTemplate().serialize());
System.out.println(enroller.getTemplate().serialize());
//prints [B@53de73a3

int blobLength = (int) blob.length();  
byte[] blobAsBytes = blob.getBytes(1, blobLength);
System.out.println(blobAsBytes);
//prints [B@3179fd59`
```

any ideas?

Edit: I also tried using array.equals() and it gave me a false output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you expect these to be the same ? You're printing using the `toString()` method on a byte array, and that's going to give you the type info + a number related to (but *not* necessarily) the memory location (it's actually the `hashCode()` when `toString()` is not overridden).

If you want to compare these, then use `equals()` on the two byte arrays. Or perhaps compare the elements one-by-one (check the length first to avoid an unnecessary traversal if the sizes don't match)

Comment: oh yeah I tried that equals too. and it gave me a "false" output.
any ways to make them equal?

Comment: I finally figured it out with some clues in your answer. thanks Brian :D

Answer (score 0):

The output of the print is the "java object id", not the content of the array

Answer (score 0):

You are not comparing the contents of the arrays, but their references.

Use [`Arrays.equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals%28byte%5B%5D,%20byte%5B%5D%29) which contains overloaded methods for the various primitive types.

Comment: I tried doing this too and had a false output. 
Am I doing the proper conversion from byte to blob here?

Comment: If you are getting false there then the contents are not equal. In that case you can try iterating over both arrays with a for loop and just stop at the first element that is not equal. Either that or look at the contents of the array in a debugger...